# XML pass using socket connection in c#

Tags: c#, xml, sockets, jboss

```
namespace SocketConnection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

        XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
        int s;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            xmldoc.Load(@"C:\Users\akshay.chopra\Desktop\chm.xml");

            NetworkStream serverstream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] writestream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmldoc.OuterXml);
            serverstream.Write(writestream, 0, writestream.Length);
            serverstream.Flush();

            s = (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize;
            byte[] readstream = new byte[s];
            serverstream.Read(readstream, 0, (int)client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readstream);
            textBox1_msg.Text = returndata;
        }

        private void textBox1_msg_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 3333);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am sending an XML to the server. The server is not sending the output XML. Kindly help in resolving this issue.

Comment: both program are made by you?

Comment: yes, I have made both of them

Comment: also update second one